# How to move any file from changes to unversioned files on any JetBrains IDEs

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I don't want to see some files on changes list. Is there any way to move or edit changes list without editing `.gitignore` file in WebStorm?

Once the open new project I suddenly clicked add always option to track version therefore I am seeing all files on changes list such as `.iml`, `.xml` files and `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Your title is unclear.

Comment: What it should be I am newbie.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add it in .gitignore then you can add it in `$GIT_DIR/.git/info/exclude`